# Fail github workflow upon failure of tests running inside a docker container

Tags: r, testing, github-actions, devtools

I am running the following step in a job of my github workflow to test an R package -

```
- name: run tests
        run: |
          docker run -i ghcr.io/<org>/<repo> R -e "devtools::test()"
```

Even when all tests do not pass, the job completes successfully. I think this is because the exit code is still 0 for the step since it did what it was supposed to do - run the tests command. How can I make the github job fail when any of the tests fail ?.

Comment: I've created an action to check command line outputs. If you know what message appears when some test fail, that could be useful if you want to take a look: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/assert-command-line-output